# wrap table down and then around rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a list of names that I would like to format into a table like the following:

```
Item.all.map(&:name)

<tr>
  <td>Apple</td>
  <td>Dragon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Banana</td>
  <td>Elephant</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cherries</td>
  <td>Flamingo</td>
</tr>
```

Such that the result looks like this to the user:

```
Apple    | Dragon
Banana   | Elephant
Cherries | Flamingo
```

etc.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `<table>` for this. It would be easier to place `<div>`s next to each other. Something like this:

Controller:

```
@list = %w(Apple Banana Cherries Dragon Elephant Flamingo)
```

CSS:

```
.float_left { float: left; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

View:

```
<div class="float_left">
<% @list.each_with_index do |item, index| %>
  <%= item %><br>
  <% if (index + 1) % 3 == 0 %>
    </div><div class="float_left">
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This should give [this result](http://jsfiddle.net/V842E/).